# Line shown on top of UITabBar

Tags: ios9, line, uitabbar, ios10, uitabbaritem

I have a custom UITabBar containing 5 buttons; the UITabBarItem in the middle is an image. This button is bigger than the remaining UITabBarItems to the left and right. On iOS9 everything worked fine, however on iOS10 there is a line being shown above the UITabBar, and I just can’t figure out where this line is coming from.

I already investigated it using the “Debug View Hierarchy” and it shows the background image and a fine line on top of the UITabBar. Unfortunately I have no idea which UIImageView is presenting this line.

Does anyone know what the issue is here? I have noticed others have had issues with the UITabBar on iOS10 but the solutions that worked for them, have not worked for me…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the shadow image of UITabBar and you can remove it just by replcaing it an empty image like below

```
yourTabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

I hope this will solve your problem, let me know if you have any difficulty.

Comment: I have tried this already, as well as this UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()